# Unable to install mkvtoolnix on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu

I tried to install mkvtoolnix and mkvtoolnix-gui on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS but it didn't work. Here is the command I ran and the output:

```
sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mkvtoolnix : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.54.0 but it is not      installable
          Depends: libboost-regex1.54.0 but it is not installable
          Depends: libboost-system1.54.0 but it is not installable
mkvtoolnix-gui : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.54.0 but it is not installable
              Depends: libboost-regex1.54.0 but it is not installable
              Depends: libboost-system1.54.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I resolve the issue of **uninstallable packages**?

Comment: I found this link when I was having the same error as well. http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/xenial/universe/m/mkvtoolnix-gui/install/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the insecure link posted above.
I installed without hassle by following the instructions on the mkvtoolnix downloads website looking in the downloads area and selecting ubuntu.

Simply open a terminal, (cntrl+shift+t or search in dash)
import the gpg key by typing: `wget -q -O - https://mkvtoolnix.download/gpg-pub-moritzbunkus.txt | sudo apt-key add -`

Run an update: `sudo apt-get update`
then run `sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui`

The program can be found in dash afterwards.